# Repeating output to the console - where do I have to insert my callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, command-line

This is my code so far:

```
var databaseUrl = "mydb";
var collections = ["users", "reports"];
var db = require("mongojs").connect(databaseUrl, collections);

newuser =       {
            email: "john@example.com",
            password: "iLoveMongo",
            sex: "male"
        };


saveuser = function(user, callback) {
    db.users.save(
        user,
        function( error, saved) {
            if( error || !saved )
                console.log( "User not saved");
            else 
                console.log( "User saved" );
                callback();
        }
    );
};

removeuser = function() {
    db.users.remove(
        {
            sex: "male"
        },
        function( error, removed)   {
            if( error || !removed )
                console.log( "User not deleted");
            else 
                console.log( "User deleted" );
        }
    );
};

finduser = function() {
    db.users.find(
        {
            sex: "male"
        },
        function(error, users) {
            if( error || !users.length )
                console.log( "No male Users found");
            else 
            {
                console.log( "male Users found" );
                users.forEach(
                    function(maleUser) {
                        console.log(maleUser);
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    )
};

updateuser = function() {
    db.users.update(
        {
            email: "john@example.com"
        },
        {
            $set: { password: "iReallyLoveMongo" }
        },
        function(err, updated) {
            if( err || !updated )
                console.log("User not updated");
            else
                console.log("User updated");
        }
    );  
}

var options = {
    1: { 
        option: "Save a User",
        execute: saveuser.bind(null, newuser, finduser)
    },
    2: { 
        option: "Remove a User",
        execute: removeuser
    },
    3: { 
        option: "Find a User",
        execute: finduser
    },
    4: { 
        option: "Update a User",
        execute: updateuser
    }
}
function read() {
    console.log("");
    console.log(" Enter your choice: ");

    stdin = process.stdin;
    stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
    stdin.on('data', choice);
};

function choice (data) {
    data = parseInt(data);

    console.log("You entered: " + data);
    console.log("You choose to do: " + options[data]["option"]);
    options[data]["execute"]();
};

read();
```

What happens is only on the first command the " Enter your choice " text pops up. You can still enter numbers and do another option.

This is what I get on the console:

```
PS C:\Users\Benni\Documents\nodejs> node .\mongotest\app.js

 Enter your choice:
1
You entered: 1
You choose to do: Save a User
User saved
male Users found
{ _id: 5386ba18463a008011fe6213,
  email: 'john@example.com',
  password: 'iLoveMongo',
  sex: 'male' }
3
You entered: 3
You choose to do: Find a User
male Users found
{ _id: 5386ba18463a008011fe6213,
  email: 'john@example.com',
  password: 'iLoveMongo',
  sex: 'male' }
```

What I want is that after every succesful command (after `options[data]["execute"]()` is done) the " Enter your choice " pops up again. Like this:

```
PS C:\Users\Benni\Documents\nodejs> node .\mongotest\app.js

 Enter your choice:
1
You entered: 1
You choose to do: Save a User
User saved
male Users found
{ _id: 5386ba18463a008011fe6213,
  email: 'john@example.com',
  password: 'iLoveMongo',
  sex: 'male' }

 Enter your choice:
3
You entered: 3
You choose to do: Find a User
male Users found
{ _id: 5386ba18463a008011fe6213,
  email: 'john@example.com',
  password: 'iLoveMongo',
  sex: 'male' }
```

Where would I have to call read() again? If I put it at the end of `choice`, the " Enter your choice" pops up before `options[data]["execute"]();` is done. If I put it at the end of `read`, I'm getting an endless loop/Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Or could I add an callback to `options[data]["execute"]();`? Something like

```
function( null, read){
  options[data]["execute"]();
};
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem that you have is that your display of the message should happen after the database method is complete. You report that completion through a callback, but *the problem is that not all your methods provide callbacks* to determine when they are done. Now even if the did, *you are not registering the callback when you invoke the method*. So you should *define a callback parameter in all your functions and then register a callback during your read*:

```
newuser =       {
            email: "john@example.com",
            password: "iLoveMongo",
            sex: "male"
        };


saveuser = function(user, callback) {
    db.users.save(
        user,
        function( error, saved) {
            if( error || !saved )
                callback( "User not saved");
            else                 
                callback(saved);
        }
    );
};

removeuser = function(callback) {
    db.users.remove(
        {
            sex: "male"
        },
        function( error, removed)   {
            if( error || !removed )
                callback( "User not deleted");
            else 
                console.log( "User deleted" );
                callback();
        }
    );
};

finduser = function(callback) {
    db.users.find(
        {
            sex: "male"
        },
        function(error, users) {
            if( error || !users.length )
                callback( "No male Users found");
            else 
            {
                console.log( "male Users found" );
                callback(null, users);
            }
        }
    )
};

updateuser = function(callback) {
    db.users.update(
        {
            email: "john@example.com"
        },
        {
            $set: { password: "iReallyLoveMongo" }
        },
        function(err, updated) {
            if( err || !updated )
                callback("User not updated");
            else
                console.log("User updated");
                callback(null, updated);
        }
    );  
}

var options = {
    1: { 
        option: "Save a User",
        execute: saveuser.bind(null, newuser)
    },
    2: { 
        option: "Remove a User",
        execute: removeuser
    },
    3: { 
        option: "Find a User",
        execute: finduser
    },
    4: { 
        option: "Update a User",
        execute: updateuser
    }
}
function read() {
    console.log("");
    console.log(" Enter your choice: ");

    stdin = process.stdin;
    stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
    stdin.on('data', choice);
};

function choice (data) {
    data = parseInt(data);

    console.log("You entered: " + data);
    console.log("You choose to do: " + options[data]["option"]);
    options[data]["execute"](function(err, res){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);                
        }
        if(res){
            if(Array.isArray(res)){
                res.forEach(function(item){
                    console.log(item);
                })
            } else {
                console.log(res);
            }
        }
        console.log(" Enter your choice: ");
    });
};

read();
```

**Using Promises**

An alternative solution for this case is to use promises. That way your invocations for the database can return a promise that you can use later on to wait for an appropriate response.

I have used [Q Promises](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q) in this answers, but you can use whatever other library you want of this sort. You can see how to get Q for your project [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/q).

We can start by making sure your database services return something, a promise in this case. For this matter I will use `Q.ninvoke` which turns a callback-based function into a promise.

```
var Q = require('q');
saveUser = function(user) {
    return Q.ninvoke(db.users,"save", user)
        .then(function(user){
            console.log("User saved: %j", user);
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log("Error while saving: %s", error);
        });
};

removeUser = function() {
    return Q.ninvoke(db.users,"remove", {sex: "male"})
        .then(function(result){
            console.log("User removed: %j", result);
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log("Error while removing: %s", error);
        });
};

findUser = function() {
    return Q.ninvoke(db.users,"find", {sex: "male"})
        .then(function(user){
            console.log("User found: %j", user);
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log("Error while finding: %s", error);
        });
};

updateUser = function() {
    return Q.ninvoke(db.users,"update", 
        {
            email: "john@example.com"
        },
        {
            $set: { password: "iReallyLoveMongo" }
        })
        .then(function(user){
            console.log("User updated: %j", user);
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log("Error while updating: %s", error);
        });
};
```

You can notice that all my service methods now return something, whereas in your original design they were void.

And finally, you can change your read program as:

```
function read() {
    console.log("");
    console.log(" Enter your choice: ");

    stdin = process.stdin;
    stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
    stdin.on('data', choice);
};

function choice (data) {
    data = parseInt(data);

    console.log("You entered: " + data);
    console.log("You choose to do: " + options[data]["option"]);
    options[data]["execute"]().then(function(){
        console.log("Enter your choice: ")
    });
};

read();
```

Notice how in this case the execution of options[data]["execute"] uses a promise. The success of the promise execution guarantees that you will not display the "Enter your choice until the other task was completed".

And voila output is:

```
Enter your choice: 
1
You entered: 1
You choose to do: Save a User
User saved: [{"email":"john@example.com","password":"iLoveMongo","sex":"male","_id":"5388f57035a2eda13b7e4ea7"},{"n":0}]
Enter your choice: 
2
You entered: 2
You choose to do: Remove a User
User removed: {"n":2}
```

Exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Hei Edwin, thank you for that! How would a proper solution without Promises look like?

Comment: @mles It would look like as I explained in first two paragraphs.

Comment: Ok I got 3 out of 4 functions modified with a callback. How about `saveuser()`? How do I modify that to have 2 callbacks? What I want to execute is `saveuser()`, then do a `finduser()` to see the inserted user, then another callback with the `function(){console.log("Enter your choice: ")}`

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, edit your function called `save` pass back in the callback the saved document, for instance `calkback(null, saved)`. That way you won't need to bind two callback parameters as you seem to imply.

Answer (score 0):

```
function choice (data) {
    data = parseInt(data);

    console.log("You entered: " + data);
    console.log("You choose to do: " + options[data]["option"]);
    options[data]["execute"]();

     process.nextTick(function(){
       console.log("");
       console.log(" Enter your choice: ");
     });    
};
```

Comment: I'm doing this in nodejs asynchronously, so the " Enter your choice " pops up before `options[data]["execute"]()` is done. I'm looking for something that puts out "Enter your choice" again **after** `options[data]["execute"]();` is done

Comment: @mles Then you need to add callbacks/promises/events to your functions so you know when they're finished.

Comment: I made some changes. The easiest way to use process.nextTick

Comment: Tried that too, adding a callback to `read()` or `choice()` but not with the results I wanted. I either got no output or it crashed with an endless loop/Maximum call stack exceeded.

Comment: @NikolayLukyanchuk getting the same output with the nextTick.

Comment: You need add callback function to your saveuser, removeuser, finduser, updateuser function. You dont show they codes, and it is difficult to create some example to help you

Answer (score 0):

You might look into using the built-in [readline](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/readline.html) module to help you with some of this:

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

function choiceHandler(choice) {
  choice = parseInt(choice, 10);
  if (isNaN(choice))
    console.log('Bad choice, try again');
  else {
    console.log('You entered: ' + choice);
    console.log('You chose to do: ' + options[choice]['option']);
  }
  rl.prompt();
}

console.log('');
rl.setPrompt(' Enter your choice: ');
rl.on('line', choiceHandler);
rl.prompt();
```

Comment: Where should I call `options[data]["execute"]()`? If I add that in the else branch, ` Enter your chouice ` still shows up before `options[data]["execute"]()` is executed

Comment: If `options[data]["execute"]()` is not guaranteed to be synchronous, then do something like `return options[data]["execute"]();` instead and call `rl.prompt();` manually when you want to show the prompt.